# App crashes when downloaded from Google Play, but works locally

Tags: java, android, reactjs, facebook, react-native

I have a working android app that I have tested in Android's Studio Emulator. When I thought I had a working version, I created a signed App Bundle and uploaded it to Google Play, but when I download it on my phone it crashes as soon as it starts to run.

I went to Google Play's ANRs & Crashes and this is the error it gives.

`com.facebook.jni.UnknownCppException`
`com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets`

```
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets (Native Method)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets (CatalystInstanceImpl.java:218)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript (JSBundleLoader.java:31)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle (CatalystInstanceImpl.java:247)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext (ReactInstanceManager.java:1152)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$900 (ReactInstanceManager.java:123)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run (ReactInstanceManager.java:943)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

I can't quite put my finger on the problem since I'm not really experienced with mobile development.

Any ideas what the problem might be related to and how to fix it?

Comment: Does the app use any external services, such as Google services, which would require an API key or something similar?  If the app be completely self-contained, then I would be surprised by your current problem.

Comment: It looks like it isn't finding a C++ library.  Are all the required .so files included, and have you ever tested locally on an actual device?

Comment: Yes, I have tested it locally. When I use a physical device to run the app like in the emulator, it works as intended. Once I make a release app bundle and install it on the phone, it crashes.